# PyScripter can not import modules in GAE SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, pyscripter

I am trying to run an app in PyScripter for python 27. It is a GAE app and uses webapp2 and jinja2. Pyscripter can not import these modules even though I have created a PYTHONPATH and added c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\lib and c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\ to this as per the advice of this post:

[import webapp2 works on google-app-engine even though I don't have webapp2 installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509276/import-webapp2-works-on-google-app-engine-even-though-i-dont-have-webapp2-insta)

I can also see that these paths have been added when I look in Tools > Python Path in PyScripter but still have an import error when I try and run the app.

Any ideas?
Thanks